# Socket Programming Server Socket TimeOut

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

If my Server Socket has a timeout using setSoTimeOut for some 10 seconds. Is 
there a way to find the ServerSocket's timeOut Property in my SocketClient ? I have a situation where ServerSocket has some timeout, I need to know in my Client and i have no knowledge about how they have configured timeOut in ServerSocket

Comment: Out of curiosity,why would you want your client know the time out property of the server?

Comment: Make a client that doesn't respond for 10 hours and check how long it takes before you get the error.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a situation where ServerSocket has some timeout, I need to know in my Client

No you don't. The requirement is self-contradictory. Until your client has connected to the server, it isn't a client at all, and there is no means by which it can know anything about the server whatsoever apart from its IP address and port number.

As far as I can see, you don't need to know in your client at all. The `ServerSocket` timeout operates when the `accept()` method has been called and there has been no inbound connection for that period. If there is a way the client can make use of that information, you need to tell us what it is.